# Map value to color rgba

Tags: performance, php, algorithm

I wrote this function to map value to a color

I am looking for some general feedback on how I can improve the efficiency of the function. and if there is better way to do it.

```
function getColor($value, $values_range, $opacity = '0.7') {

       $deltaS = ($values_range['max'] - $values_range['min']) / 2;
       $ds = ($value - $values_range['min']) / $deltaS;
       $nearest_color_index = floor($ds);
       $alpha = $ds - $nearest_color_index;

      $r = $g = $b = -1;
      $colors = [['r'=>255,'g' => 60,'b' => 40],
                 ['r' => 255,'g' => 247,'b' =>40],
                 ['r' => 12,'g' => 197,'b' => 17]];

      if ($nearest_color_index != 2) {
             $r = round($colors[$nearest_color_index]['r'] + $alpha * ($colors[$nearest_color_index + 1]['r'] - $colors[$nearest_color_index]['r']));
             $g = round($colors[$nearest_color_index]['g'] + ($alpha * ($colors[$nearest_color_index + 1]['g'] - $colors[$nearest_color_index]['g'])));
             $b = round($colors[$nearest_color_index]['b'] + $alpha * ($colors[$nearest_color_index + 1]['b'] - $colors[$nearest_color_index]['b']));

             return "rgba($r,$g,$b,$opacity)";  

     } else {
          $r = round($colors[$nearest_color_index]['r']);
          $g = round($colors[$nearest_color_index]['g']);
          $b = round($colors[$nearest_color_index]['b']);
          return "rgba($r,$g,$b,$opacity)";
  }

 }
```

Comment: is this in a class or purely functional ?

Comment: @Dan it's a purely function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Function name

The function name `getColor` isn't representative of what it does its better of being named `createRgbaString` (or something along those lines)

### Return early

Your script returns in two different places, this should be changed so you exit the function early, it saves an else statement and a level of identing

### Variable nameing style

Your variable naming style is not compatible with PSR2 but that isn't the end of the world.

### Line length

Your line length exceeds 80 character line length, this is again not the end of the world but will make it hard to read for some people

### Repeated calculation

Your repeatedly do the same calculation if the `$index != 2` I would move this into a function so if it needs to be updated you only have todo it in one location

### How I might write it

**I have used terrible variable names**, because I don't have the time do work out the complete logic of your script, so this should be unit tested if your going to use it

```
function getColor($value, $values_range, $opacity = '0.7')
{
    $deltaS = ($values_range['max'] - $values_range['min']) / 2;
    $ds = ($value - $values_range['min']) / $deltaS;
    $nearest_color_index = floor($ds);
    $alpha = $ds - $nearest_color_index;

    $r = $g = $b = -1;

    $colors = [
        ['r'=>255,'g' => 60,'b' => 40],
        ['r' => 255,'g' => 247,'b' =>40],
        ['r' => 12,'g' => 197,'b' => 17]
    ];

    $rNormal = getColorIndexPlusModifier($nearest_color_index, "r", 0, $colors);
    $gNormal = getColorIndexPlusModifier($nearest_color_index, "g", 0, $colors);
    $bNormal = getColorIndexPlusModifier($nearest_color_index, "b", 0, $colors);

    if ($nearest_color_index == 2) {
        return "rgba($rNormal,$gNormal,$bNormal,$opacity)";
    }

    $rPlusOne = getColorIndexPlusModifier($nearest_color_index, "r", 1, $colors);
    $gPlusOne = getColorIndexPlusModifier($nearest_color_index, "g", 1, $colors);
    $bPlusOne = getColorIndexPlusModifier($nearest_color_index, "b", 1, $colors);

    $r = doCalculation($rNormal, $alpha, $rPlusOne);
    $g = doCalculation($gNormal, $alpha, $gPlusOne);
    $b = doCalculation($bNormal, $alpha, $bPlusOne);

    return "rgba($r,$g,$b,$opacity)";
}

function getColorIndexPlusModifier($colorIndex, $colorString, $toModifyBy, $colors)
{
    return round($colors[$colorIndex + $toModifyBy][$colorString]);
}
//TODO Rename to something meaningful 
function doCalculation($normalValue, $alpha, $plusOneValue)
{
    return round($normalValue + $alpha * ($plusOneValue - $normalValue));
}
```